Hidden Unicode General Collation via mysqli_get_charset even though everything else is 520 and 1400
I did a server migration and have been doing an audit. On the new server I finally had the freedom to upgrade MariaDB to 10.11 (needed 10.10 to get Unicode 14.0 support) and was previously stuck at Unicode 5.2 support.
I've tracked this via print_r(mysqli_get_charset($db)); in PHP. After changing the server collation (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%coll%';) everything shows up correctly as utf8mb4_uca1400_ai_ci. I haven't updated the databases or tables yet which are all still utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci which is fine for now.
The problem is that print_r(mysqli_get_charset($db)); returns utf8mb4_general_ci. So I investigated by starting on my local MariaDB install since I have the all-queries log running. When you run that command in PHP it translates to the following query:
SELECT `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME`='__database_name_here__';

Okay, so I took that query and ran it on the live server and get utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci (again, fine for now). For non-related reasons I've restarted the server several times so this shouldn't be a "stuck-in-memory" problem.
So where is mysqli_get_charset($db) getting the utf8mb4_general_ci collation so I can update it?

i think you get the connection character set, see if the php connction has also general as character set

What collation is on the columns?  The collation on a table is only a default for new columns.

I filed a PHP bug report and in short: they have an internal static array of character sets with utf8mb4_general_ci as a fallback. So the appropriate way to get the character set information is by this query:
SELECT VARIABLE_NAME, GLOBAL_VALUE, DEFAULT_VALUE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_VARIABLES 
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME LIKE '%CHAR%';

